# How to set timeout for consumer(rabbitmq)

Tags: rabbitmq, consumer

I use SimpleMessageListenerContainer to consume message from rabbitMQ queue.

EVN:

1. rabbitmq:3.6.6
2. spring-rabbit:1.6.2

CODE:

```
@Bean
public SimpleMessageListenerContainer listenerContainer() {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory());
    container.setQueues(new Queue("spring.demo"));
    container.setMaxConcurrentConsumers(1);
    container.setConcurrentConsumers(1);
    container.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.MANUAL);

    container.setMessageListener(new ChannelAwareMessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws Exception {
            long deliveryTag = message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag();
            try {
                byte[] body = message.getBody();
                String result = new String(body);
                logger.debug("result:" + result);

                // doSomething(for a long time)

                channel.basicAck(deliveryTag, false);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                channel.basicNack(deliveryTag, false, false);
            }
        }
    });

    return container;
}
```

There has 1 consumer to handle message. Now If a message will handle in a long time(5minutes), then other message can not to be consumed.

I want to set a timeout for each handle message. For example,set timeout is 30 seconds. If a Message handle over this value(30 seconds) then the consumer throw Exception to over handle.  Thus this consumer can handle other message.

But now I do not know  how to set this timeout?